# Kivmob banner ads not showing after convert android apk

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, buildozer, kivmob

I am trying to show Test ada on kivy application using kivmob. Reward video ads and Interstitials ada working correctly but banner ads not showing banner. I am compiling sample code for banner provide by [kivmob](http://kivmob.com/tutorials.html)

```
from kivmob import KivMob,TestIds

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class BannerTest(App):
    """ Displays a banner ad at top of the screen.
    """

    def build(self):
        self.ads = KivMob(TestIds.APP)
        self.ads.new_banner(TestIds.BANNER, top_pos=True)
        self.ads.request_banner()
        self.ads.show_banner()
        return Label(text='Banner Ad Demo')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BannerTest().run()
```

.spec file

```
requirements = python3,hostpython3, kivy==2.1.0, android, pyjnius, kivmob
...
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.api = 30
android.minapi = 21
android.sdk = 24
android.ndk = 23b
android.gradle_dependencies = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
p4a.branch = master
android.meta_data=com.google.android.gms.ada.APPLICATION_ID=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
```

I am using python 3.7 kivy 2.1.0 debug with google collabs

Thank you.

I am trying to show banner ads but not working